# Sampling a 2-dimensional surface: How many samples along X & Y axes?

Tags: optics, computational-physics, numerical-method

I have a set of first 25 [Zernike polynomials](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.2644&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Below are shown few in Cartesin co-ordinate system.

```
z2 = 2*x

z3 = 2*y

z4 = sqrt(3)*(2*x^2+2*y^2-1)
```

:

:

```
z24 = sqrt(14)*(15*(x^2+y^2)^2-20*(x^2+y^2)+6)*(x^2-y^2)
```

I am not using 1st since it is piston; so I have these 24 two-dim ANALYTICAL functions expressed in X-Y Cartesian co-ordinate system. All are defined over unit circle, as they are orthogonal over unit circle. The problem which I am describing here is relevant to other 2D surfaces also apart from Zernike Polynomials.

Suppose that origin (0,0) of the XY co-ordinate system and the centre of the unit circle are same.

Next, I take linear combination of these 24 polynomials to build a 2D wavefront shape. I use 24 random input coefficients in this combination.

```
w(x,y) = sum_over_i   a_i*z_i         (i=2,3,4,....24)

a_i = random coefficients
z_i = zernike polynomials
```

Upto this point, everything is analytical part which can be done on paper.

Now comes the discretization!

I know that when you want to re-construct a signal (1Dim/2Dim), your sampling frequency should be at least twice the maximum frequency present in the signal (Nyquist-Shanon principle).

Here signal is w(x,y) as mentioned above which is nothing but a simple 2Dim
function of x & y. I want to represent it on computer now. Obviously I can not take all infinite points from -1 to +1 along x axis and same for y axis.
I have to take finite no. of data points (which are called sample points or just samples) on this analytical 2Dim surface w(x,y)

I am measuring x & y in metres, and

```
 -1 <= x <= +1; -1 <= y <= +1
```

e.g. If I divide my x-axis from -1 to 1, in 50 sample points then dx = 2/50= 0.04 metre. Same for y axis. Now my sampling frequency is 1/dx i.e. 25 samples per metre. Same for y axis.

But I took 50 samples arbitrarily; I could have taken 10 samples or 1000 samples. That is the crux of the matter here: how many samples points?How will I determine this number?

There is one theorem (Nyquist-Shanon theorem) as mentioned above which says that if I want to re-construct w(x,y) faithfully, I must sample it on both axes so that my sampling frequency (i.e. no. of samples per metre) is at least twice the maximum frequency present in the w(x,y). This is nothing but finding power spectrum of w(x,y). Idea is that any function in space domain can be represented in spatial-frequency domain also, which is nothing but taking Fourier transform of the function! This tells us how many (spatial) frequencies are present in your function w(x,y) and what is the maximum frequency out of these many frequencies.

Now my question is first how to find out this maximum sampling frequency in my case. I can not use MATLAB fft2() or any other tool since it means already I have samples taken across the wavefront!! Obviously remaining option is find it analytically ! But that is time consuming and difficult since I have 24 polynomials & I will have to use then continuous Fourier transform i.e. I will have to go for pen and paper.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Functions on a circle with angular frequency components up to $n$ and average 0 form a vector space of dimension $2n$ spanned by (e.g.) $\cos(2\pi nx)$ and $\sin(2\pi nx)$, so you need at least $2n$ samples to reconstruct it. In this case taking samples at regular intervals of length $1/(2n)$ of each basis element gives you a linearly independent set of $2n$ elements in a $2n$-dimensional space, so the original can be reconstructed.

For 24 linearly independent functions you need 24 samples at appropriate points. To know if e.g. taking 12 equispaced points between -1 and 1 in $x$ and the same in $y$ gives you a linearly independent set depends on the polynomials you are using. Note that your reconstruction is by inverting the change of basis matrix, and will generally not be as fast as inverting the Fourier transform (for 24 elements that is not an issue of course).

Comment: Sorry, I did not get how does 2n-dimensional space come in the picture? Zernike polynomials need 2-dimensions namely x & y, for their definition. Will you please elaborate on this? and what about Nyquist-Shanon principle ?

Comment: @atom a function of frequency up to $n$ can be written as a linear combination of the 2n basis elements $\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x),\cos(4\pi x),\ldots,\cos(n\pi x),\sin(n\pi x)$, which are 2n linearly independent elements, so their span, the set of all functions containing frequency components up to n is 2n-dimensional. This doesn't have to do with the dimension of their domain. If you sample them at frequency 2n they turn into vectors with 2n components

Comment: I am not mathematician like you. Please see edited version of my question. I am not getting you at all. I am using Noll indexing for nomenclature of Zernike polynomials. I am looking at the problem from a practical point of view. I still have no idea of "a function of frequency upto n.....".

Comment: @atom I am not saying anything deep, probably I just didn't say it very clearly. I am sure you know the math involved, which is just linear algebra. What I said is not specific to a given set of (linearly independent) functions. As an example, assume you have funcions f,g,h and a random (unknown) linear combination $af + bg + ch$. You want to find $a,b,c$. For this you can fix points $x,y,z$ in which the vectors of sampled values $(f(x), f(y), f(z)), (g(x), g(y), g(z)), (h(x), h(y), h(z))$ are linearly independent in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Your unknown function $\phi = af + bg + ch$ will give another element $(\phi(x), \phi(y), \phi(z))$ of $\Bbb R^3$. From this you can find $a,b,c$. Try it out for an example, e.g. $f(X) = 1, g(X) = X, h(X) = X^2$, and $x,y,z = -1,0,1$. For $f(X) = 1, g(X) = X^2, h(X) = X^4$ these interpolation points wouldn't but you could take 0,1,2. Three random points will usually do. Functions with frequency up to $n$ are spanned by $\sin(2\pi x), \cos(2\pi x),\ldots\sin(2\pi nx), \cos(2\pi nx)$, $2n$ linearly independent functions, so you need $2n$ points, twice the maximal frequency

Comment: In your example you need at least 24 points (in the plane). If your polynomials evaluated in these points are linearly independent in $\Bbb R^{24}$, you can reconstruct your random linear combination. If you sample in more than 24 points, you can do a least square approximation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) which should give you the same result.

Comment: Btw, the thing about the functions of different frequencies is just there to illustrate how the Nyquist-Shannon theorem is in a way a special case of this.

Comment: Will you please tell any good introductory textbook about the functions of different frequencies and Nyquist-Shannon theorem and all that stuff ? Where I can find this material on web (except wikipedia)?

Comment: I don't really know a specific reference, but essentially the math will all be in an introductory textbook on linear algebra. For specific examples close to your application, look for polynomials, function spaces, Fourier series and least squares.